# How to add a Particle Texture?

Tags: texturing, interface, particles

I am new to blender and working through a tutorial, but I have a problem. I can not for the life of me figure out how to add a particle texture. I must be missing something in the UI. When I navigate to the texture tab I can not find the button. What am I doing wrong?

[image: question]

in case anyone is wondering the tutorial is here:
http://blenderdiplom.com/en/tutorials/all-tutorials/394-tutorial-dissolve-your-logo-in-blender-262.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the particle tab of the properties window and add a new particle system to your object. In the particle settings look for the *Textures* panel and add a new texture.

If you return to the textures panel it should then turn into particle texture editing, along with a pull-down menu to choose texture context from.

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! I feel kind of dumb, you wouldn't believe how much time I spent poking around looking for this.

Comment: You helped me answer my own question https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173192/driving-hair-from-a-texture/173348#173348. The way the image has to be selected in different tabs is particularly confusing.