# Random Particle Image Textures

Tags: texturing, particles

I was looking at this post ([How to add a Particle Texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106250/how-to-add-a-particle-texture)) and was wondering if it were possible to set the particles to random image textures such as playing cards.

Currently, I have a particle emitter that just shoots out card shaped cuboids. Do I 
need to add each individual card texture to the particle texture tab and add texture randomisation there or do I need to set up the Dupli Object (render tab of textures) to randomise the textures? Ether or I'm not sure how to achieve texture randomisation. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What render engine do you intend to work with? Should it be in 2.79b or 2.80?

Comment: @Jackdaw Im going to use 2.79b Cycles Render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setup is a bit fiddly but it gets the job done :-P

[image: Render]

[image]

The particle system needs to be set to render a UV unwrapped object, in this case it's a simple plane.

(The billboard particle sadly doesn't work in cycles 2.79b. In Blender Internal there is already functionality to randomise with tiles in the billboard particle settings.)

[image: Node network for material]

I am using the object random input in the material to get a normalised random scalar (0 - 1). I can then use this to scale and offset the uvmap to select one of 4 images in a texture.

The input value (2) is the number of horizontal and vertical tiles and can be changed if needed.

[image: Texture with 2 x 2 tiles]

Comment: Would it be too cheeky of me to ask you to add the file to the post? I never really got too deep into the node editor and that looks a little intimidating. With the file it is easier to play around and see how this whole thing works.

Comment: Sure... just needed to learn how to do that properly first :-) I have updated the my answer with a link to the blender file just below the render.

Comment: Thank you,  it's a lot more clear now what I have to do.