# Driving Hair from a Texture

Tags: particles

I want to grow grass (hair particle system) driving by a texture instead of by a weight paint (because vertices are not accurate enough for my purposes).

According to my understanding, this should be possible using the *Vertex Weight Edit* modifier, as seen in [Vertex group from texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3355/vertex-group-from-texture). However, the `.blend` file included in that response does not even work, and I am unable to figure out how to set this up.

[image: grass driving by texture]

As an example, I want to grow grass in the white areas, and have no grass in the black areas.

Here is the `.blend` file I set up so far:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A sleepless night brought up the following question: [How to add a Particle Texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106250/how-to-add-a-particle-texture)

The steps are finicky but work well:

1. Create the particle system, and create/paint a new texture; include it as the object texture if you want to see what you're doing (the object's texture/material won't affect the particle system).
2. In the *Particle Properties* tab there's a dropdown called *Textures*. Select your texture.
3. In the *Texture Properties* tab, go under the *Image > Settings* dropdown and select your image (again).
4. At the very top of the *Texture Properties* tab, set the dropdown to *ParticleSettings - Texture*.
5. Finally, under *Influence* (still in *Texture Properties*), check *Density* to let the image drive particle density.

Also, for the particles to appear at the right place on a non-square surface, it may be necessary to select the UV unwrap for the particle system to match the texture placement. That's under *Texture Properties > Mapping > Coordinates*, select UV.

Steps 3 and 4 are particularly strange at first, but work well after all. Tabbing in/out of edit mode will reflect the particle system changes. Then, to texture paint the hair, go to texture paint mode and paint more white on the texture, remembering to tab in/out of texture paint mode to update the particle system.