# How to apply a texture to a particle system?

Tags: modeling, animation, texturing, uv, particles

I want to apply a texture to a particle system, but I don't know how. Many other people seem to have answered this question, but no matter how many times I try the steps, they never work. I'm also using the Molecular addon for my particle system, if that's important at all. [image]

Comment: you need to assign a material to your particle object like you would do it for any object. For the moment you are in the Texture panel, you need to click on the Material panel, create a new material, and work it in a Shader Editor window.

Comment: Can you give an example where this question is answered which steps you can't get to work? If you know answers that suit you it would be best to tell us where or why you fail.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I'm trying to apply a UV map to a particle system, not a texture. I've tried applying the UV map to the particle object as well, but that doesn't work. As for the steps where I fail, I've been trying to follow this explanation: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/106250/how-to-add-a-particle-texture
I don't fail at any step in particular, it just never affects the particle system.